# i want print 1 to n number by help of recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(10);
    }
    static void print(int s)
    {
        if (1==s) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.print(s);
        print(s-1);
    }
}
```

But I want output like this:

```
12345678910
```

Comment: your current code work? (other than printing in the other direction)

Answer (score 2):

You existing recursion never ends. You should only make the recursive call if `s >= 1`.

And to print the numbers in increasing order, you need to first make the recursive call and then print the current number:

```
static void print(int s)
{
    if (s >= 1) {
      print(s-1);
      System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. To intuitively understand this - imagine a stack. Each `print(s-1)` means push to the stack. Then after condition `s>=1` doesn't hold any more, the values get popped from the stack and printed.

Comment: A very thanks bro it's really work, but I am little bit confuse that after the program recursively call print(s-1) done .How it returning number in reverse order to sout();

Comment: @AdityaPandey print(10) calls print(9) which calls print(8).... which calls print(1) which calls print (0) which does nothing and returns to print(1) which prints 1 and returns to print(2) which prints 2 and returns to print(3).... print(9) prints 9 and returns to print(10) which prints 10 and finishes

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(1, 10);
}

static void print(int startValue, int endValue)
{
    System.out.print(startValue);
    if(startValue < endValue)
       print(startValue+1, endValue);
}
```

Comment: Bro I try this earlier, but i want that the program take only one parameter......

Comment: Then you can just hardcode endValue as 10 in condition line if you still want to use this code. I provided this code because it is more intuitive than @Eran's. If you don't want to hardcode it then I would suggest you to use his solution

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**- If you want the end result-oriented then you can try this

```
public static int doCalculaton(int numVal, int endVal) {
    System.out.println(endVal - numVal);
    if (numVal == 0) {
        return numVal;
    }
    return doCalculaton(numVal - 1, endVal);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int toBeCalculateNum = 10;
    doCalculaton(toBeCalculateNum, toBeCalculateNum);
}
```

**Solution 2:**- If you want to use the result after calling

```
public static int doCalculaton(int numVal, ArrayList<Integer> numerList) {
        numerList.add(numVal);
        if (numVal == 0) {
            return numVal;
        }
        return doCalculaton(numVal - 1, numerList);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numerList = new ArrayList<>();
        doCalculaton(10, numerList);
        Collections.reverse(numerList);
        System.out.println(numerList);

        // TODO loop and do whatever you want to do

    }
```

Comment: Bro for solution 1 i already tried this but i want that program take only one parameter and for solution 2 : i think it earlier to include array list but i don't want that  program let to be too long ...